# How do I get a notify event on a property that's at the top level in the polymer-starter-kit?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

So the basic starter kit has a variable 'route' (a string for the current page being shown), which if it were a component I'd just add a notify:true to the properties in the JSON, which is part of the Polymer(...) call.

But the example doesn't wrap the top level in Polymer(...), so how do I set it to notify on change?

I can add the event listener to the #app fine, but it won't send that event without knowing it has to.

All I want to do is get an event when the current page changes, so I'm sure I'm just overlooking something pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create an element that is bound to the top-level attribute and fires off an event.

So in your index.html:

```
<body ...>
<template is="dom-bind">
    <my-route-watcher route="{{route}}">
</template>
</body>
```

and in your my-route-watcher.html:

```
<dom-module id="my-route-watcher">

<script>
Polymer({
   is: "my-route-watcher",

   properties: {
       route: {
           type: String,
           notify: true
       }
   }
   routeChanged: function() {
        this.fire('the-route-changed', { msg: "woohoo" });
   }
});

</script>
</dom-module>
```